# httpd: stickysession and nofailover

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

i have config file contains:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
RewriteEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" env=HTTPS


<Proxy "balancer://webtop">
    BalancerMember "http://internalsite:7003" route=web1 ping=2
    BalancerMember "http://internalsite:7006" route=web2 ping=2
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests 
</Proxy>

<Location /webtop>
    ProxyPass balancer://webtop/webtop stickysession=ROUTEID nofailover=On
    Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/webtop" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
</Location>2
</VirtualHost>
```

Questions:

1. First connect. We have no routeid cookie. Could balancer check BalancerMember status before first assigning to prevent assign to inactive BalanceMember?
2. Something happens. We have routeid cookie, for example, web1, but this  BalancerMember is down. We make new request. Could httpd automaticaly change cookie to web2 and switch to this BalanceMember?

i'm trying to config apache httpd as balancer

Answer (score 0):

1. First connect. We have no routeid cookie. Could balancer check BalancerMember status before first assigning to prevent assign to inactive BalanceMember?

> > The cookie can either be set by the backend.You can set cookies at ProxyPass or ProxySet.  The balancer extracts the value of the cookie and looks for a member worker with a route equal to that value.

2. Something happens. We have routeid cookie, for example, web1, but this BalancerMember is down. We make new request. Could httpd automatically change cookie to web2 and switch to this BalanceMember?

> > Yes.  If nofailover is set to On, the session will break if the worker is in an error state or disabled. Set this value to On if backend servers do not support session replication.